# MantisBT not listing changelog

Tags: mantis

I am making use of MantisBT to track issues and have so far collected a number of issues. However, my changelog remains empty

> No Change Log information available. Issues are included once projects
>   have versions and issues are resolved with "fixed in version" set.

Each bug report has 
Product version, target version (needed for roadmap) and a fixed in version (needed for changelog).
Likewise I have released certain versions.

I have customized my workflow and I suspect this is part of the reason.

```
# custom access list
$g_access_levels_enum_string = '10:VIEWER,20:REPORTER,30:ENGINEER,40:CCB,90:ADMINISTRATOR';

# custom resolution list
$g_resolution_enum_string = '10:OPEN,20:REOPEN,30:WONTFIX,60:DISPOSITIONED, 70:FIXED';
```

From what I have been able to determine, for a changelog to appear you need
1) a released version (done)
2) a bug with a fixed in version matching this (done
3) a bug closed as "fixed"

now in a fresh MantisBT (and testing shows changelog works),  FIXED has a constant of 20 so part of me suspect it is my g_resolution_enum_string but this would also imply that there should be another variable that sets which threshold should be used

```
$g_bug_resolution_fixed_threshold = FIXED;
```

This does not work

What am I missing?  Also if it is of importance... my versions are labeled:  v0.0, v0.1, v0.2  (ie prepended by 'v')

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the documentation's [Enumerations section](http://mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html-desktop/#admin.customize.enums), in particular

> The strings included in the enumerations here are just for documentation purposes

So, your enum definition of `70:FIXED` does not actually match the constant *FIXED* which, as you have pointed out, is still set to 20 which means that *$g_bug_resolution_fixed_threshold* actually points to your `20:REOPEN`... You may want to define your own constants.

Also note that there is another important threshold in this context, `$g_bug_resolution_not_fixed_threshold` - resolutions above it are considered to be resolved in an unsuccessful way. By default it is set to _UNABLE_TO_REPRODUCE_ (40).

In other words, for an issue to appear in the Changelog, it must match all of the following criteria ([reference](http://[enter%20link%20description%20here][2])):

- status >= bug_resolution_fixed_threshold
- resolution >= bug_resolution_fixed_threshold
- resolution < bug_resolution_not_fixed_threshold

Note that this standard behavior can be changed with a [custom function](http://mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html-desktop/#admin.customize.customfuncs).

So your problem is indeed caused by your custom *resolution_enum_string*, most likely in combination with the values in the 2 above-mentioned thresholds.